# Remove 'using System.Linq' statment from all C# pages

Tags: visual-studio-2012, using-directives

I have this source in all the c# pages

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
```

I want to REMOVE all the

> using System.Linq;

Lines from my existing c# pages in one solution.

I have

> visual studio 2012 for web

it is possible to do that without delete in every page this line?

Wish for help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CRTL+F`, select find and replace
Then type in `using System.Linq;`, replace by nothing

Select current Project or in your case the Entire solution and go

You will have blank lines but that should be no issue

Answer (score 3):

Use Replace In Files with regular expressions turned on and replace `using System\.Linq;\n` with nothing.